# Update 500+ field records to include an increment value + attribute value

Tags: mysql, sql

Im looking to update 500+ records in my mysql database so that the fields will be a value combination of an `$incremental_value+db_user_first_name+@some_static_text`. An example of the wished outcome:

1_firstname@staticstring.com, 2_george@staticstring.com, 3_johnny@staticstring.com etc.

I've been playing around with some approach as the following, but that naturally doesn't work (modified for hopefully better clarification).

```
UPDATE user
SET email = (($incremental_value+1)+(user.first_name))"@staticstring.com"
WHERE email = "empty@empty.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for string concatenation in MySQL is the `concat()` function:

```
UPDATE user cross join
       (select @i = VALUETOSTART) var
    SET email = concat(@i := @i + 1, '_', user.first_name, '@staticstring.com')
    WHERE email = 'empty@empty.com';
```